# Using Contains with List of String?

Tags: c#, linq

I have below code

```
var project = db.Projects.FirstOrDefault(x => projectIds.Contains(x.ProjectId));
```

If `projectIds` is a `List<string>` contains "1234567", and `x.ProjectId` is **"1234"**, it will return project has `ProjectId` is **1234**.

How can I get exactly project if its' `ProjectId` is **"1234567"**?

Thank for your support!

Comment: In first case you should ask your self, why is an Project ID of type nvarchar?!

Comment: Are you sure that your code is not working? Your calling the Contains method of a List not on a string so it should check if the lists contains an exact match!

Comment: What happens if you don't use LINQ but a plain old for?

Comment: Wait a second. What ids are in `projectIds` ? Does it *also* contain "1234" ?

Comment: If you want a project with one specific id, you should search with that id ,only. Not a set of ids.

Answer (score 3):

`Contains` actually looks for substring in it, you need here is full match so you can try using `==` operator here like:

```
var project = db.Projects.FirstOrDefault(x => projectIds.Any(id=> id ==x.ProjectId))
```

This will now make sure to match the complete string value in it.

Comment: If the `projectIds` is a `List<string>` and `x.ProjectId` is `string`, there is absolutely no difference between the `Contains` and what you are suggesting.

Comment: List.Contains does not look for substring: https://dotnetfiddle.net/XMEHy3

Comment: List.Contains works similar to indexOf, just looks for a match within the string and returns a bool if it finds it... so saying it looks for a substring is correct although it can be a full string as well

Comment: let me try in a fiddle and post the example

Comment: another thing to consider is, here it is Linq to Entities, it will get translated int to sql, so Sql might be generate query using  `like`

Comment: @EhsanSajjad I am suspecting something like that, yes. But a plain List<string>.Contains will not match substrings. I'd have to refactor a lot of code if it were so. And also a lot of my tests would fail.

Comment: I think here is some confusion between string.Contains and IQueryable<string>.Contains

Comment: @EhsanSajjad As we all know, `Enumerable.Contains` is translated to SQL `IN (val1, val2, ...)`.

Comment: @IvanStoev if that's the case, the OP code should have returned no result, but according to him it returns result back

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Indeed. That's why the question is unclear and needs further clarification / mcve by OP.

Answer (score 0):

Contains work as SQL like wildcards, to get exact result you need to use .Any extension instead of contains. please see the example to understand.

```
string[] x = { "abcd", "abc" };
string[] y = { "abcd", "abc", "abcde" };
var result= x.FirstOrDefault(a => y.Any(b => b == a));

result=abcd
```

**Answer**

```
var result = db.Projects.FirstOrDefault(x => projectIds.Any(p=> p==x.ProjectId))
```

Comment: "Contains work as SQL like wildcards" - which `Contains`? `string.Contains` or `List<string>.Contains` or ... ?

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't use

```
var project = db.Projects.FirstOrDefault(x => projectIds.Any(id=> id ==x.ProjectId))
```

string.Equals was made for a reason,

```
var project = db.Projects.FirstOrDefault(x => projectIds.Any(id=> id.Equals(x.ProjectId))
```

Then in the future you can include all the overrides that it comes with such as ignoring case and culture. In your case culture might be worth it. E.g if a Korean windows was running your program.

Comment: why down vote ? am i wrong? -I love a down vote with no explanation

Comment: I guess it was because this answer is not answering the question.